# How to solve encoding when piping file from NodeJs Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, stream, pipe

I'm attempting to pipe a file in Firebase bucket through a nodeJS cloud function to the client (browser). The client will use `file-saver.js` to start the download on the browser.

This works well with `text/plain` mime types but produces corrupt files with images and pngs. The issue is with encoding, as I can see the data that reaches the client is not encoded properly.

Here is an example response on client side w/ an image:

```
data: "�PNG↵↵IHDR%�*���sBIT|d�...
```

**How should I properly pipe the file back to maintain the correct encoding?**

Here is the current cloud function:

```
const filesBucket = admin.storage().bucket(FILES_BUCKET_NAME);

function getFile(fileName, res){
  const filePath = fileName
  const file = filesBucket.file(filePath)

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', getMimeType(fileName));
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+fileName);

  file.createReadStream()
    .on('error', err => {
        // not good
    })
    .on('response', function(response) {
        // ok
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        // The file is fully downloaded.
    })
    .pipe(res); // pipe the file back to client
}
```

Here is the client side part:

```
export const getFile = (filename) =>{
   ...
   axios.get(fileUrl, config)
     .then(resp => {
         downloadFile(resp.data, filename, getMimeType(filename))
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log("getCurrentUserFile | err", err)
         reject(err)
     })

function downloadFile(data, filename, mimeType){
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: mimeType});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how file-saver save file but I was able to download files with below setup and might help you.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myFunction()">

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    var contentType = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
                    var fileExtention;
                    if (contentType) {

                        fileExtention = contentType.split('/')[1]

                    }

                    //console.log(this.responseText)
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";

                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = "demo." + fileExtention
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    a.remove();
                }
            };
            xhttp.responseType = 'blob'
            xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/getfile", true);
            xhttp.send();

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Nodejs:**

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/getfile', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    //res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+'test.png');
    fs.createReadStream('./demo.png').pipe(res)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried to pipe a local .png or .pdf file from server like your example as well as save it wo/ file-saver as shown here. https://blog.jayway.com/2017/07/13/open-pdf-downloaded-api-javascript/

still the same outcome, the .pdf and .png files downloaded are corrupt. Originals are fine.

Comment: @KasparTr I think you are not passing correct value for Content-Type. For images it should be `image/imagetype` for example `image/png` and for pdf application/pdf.

Comment: Also while downloading  you should be able to give a correct file extension as per the `content-type` response header

Comment: Not sure what you meant by the last comment, but I just double checked the MIME types and they are correctly set in the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the client side, using [FileSaver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) and nothing with encoding.

Once I used this,it worked:

```
axios({
    url: fileUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    params:{...},
    responseType: 'blob', // <--important
}).then((resp) => {
     const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp.data]));
     const link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = url;
     link.setAttribute('download', filename);
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
});
```

[Credit where credit it due](https://thewebtier.com/snippets/download-files-with-axios/)